# Simple geometry in a Foucault Pendulum derivation

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

It is of course a physics subject, but I'm having problem with the geometry. In all the derivations I see that by similar triangles:
$$ \frac{T_x}{T}= -\frac{x}{L}$$

I tried to get this result by scribbling the triangles, using angles etc but I don't see how that follows so easily. The minus sign is a product of the physics, but the ratio itself doesn't seem clear to me. If someone could please show me explicitly how by geometry this ratio follows it will greatly help. Where are the similar triangles and why?

Comment: Connect the endpoints and try to prove that those two similar triangles both contain a right angle.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm having problem with... How can you deduce the smaller triangle has a right angle?

Comment: The vector $T_x$ is the projection of $T$ on $x$ right? By its definition, the smaller triangle must have a right angle.

Comment: Excuse me, but why is it by definition? I know once I'll get it, it will seem extremely trivial, I just fail to see why if I close that small triangle I necessarily get a right triangle.

Comment: I think it will be clear as soon as you see the picture.. https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Vector_projection#:~:text=The%20projection%20of%20a%20vector,Both%20are%20vectors.&text=For%20a%20given%20vector%20and,equal%20to%20the%20original%20vector.